# Setting a nested array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new to C++, and I have a question that should be easy, but it's making me crazy. I'm trying to set up a 2D array. The array is declared in `Solver.h` like so:

```
 protected:
    static const int gridSize = 9;
    int theGrid[gridSize][gridSize]
    int *boxes[gridSize][gridSize];
...
```

and I'm trying to initialize it in `Solver::Solver()` like so:

```
boxes[0] ={ &theGrid[0][0],&theGrid[0][1],&theGrid[0][2],
            &theGrid[1][0],&theGrid[1][1],&theGrid[1][2],
            &theGrid[2][0],&theGrid[2][1],&theGrid[2][2] 
          };
...
```

But the error I'm getting says "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" *and* "error: expected an expression". This didn't make sense to me, because I was under the impression that `boxes[0]` *was* a modifiable lvalue.

So I wrote a tiny little (non OOP) program that just has the following in it's `main()`:

```
int test[2][2];
test[0]= {1,2};
cout<<test[0][1];   //outputs "2" as expected.
```

And now I'm stuck and confused. What is wrong with my assignment routine in the Solver class?

To answer some questions:

I do want a multidimensional array, because eventually I'll be setting up `boxes[1]` with another array of pointers to another set of data inside the `theGrid`, a third set in `boxes[2]` and so on. The idea is to take a 9x9 grid and split it into 3x3 squares (sound familiar? "Solver" should solve sudoku sets simply.) so I can check (and modify) all the values in those 3x3 squares independently.
I'm trying to get this working in VS2010. 
I'm sure there's a good algorithm to define which array members are part of each 3x3 "box" based on that boxes number but I haven't hit it yet, and it seems less wasteful to code it once than to have the program re-create those boxes in loops every time it checks an answer. For the scope of this program the size of `theGrid` is inalterable, so my conscience will let me get away with a little hard coding.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish -- i.e., what is `boxes` supposed to be able to do that `theGrid` can't (or vice versa)? Why do you (think you) want both at all?

Comment: A wild guess: maybe it's trying to create a pointer to an array instead of an array of pointers? (not putting this as an answer because I don't know for sure, I'm just guessing)

Comment: do you want to declare grid size as 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `{ ... }` is not an expression, it is an initializer. Some compilers have an extension to allow expressions to be formed using `{}`, and C++0x adds several new meanings to the braces, but I'm going to keep this to standard C++.

I think the best general solution is to code a loop. You don't really want to write all that redundancy out, right?

```
Solver::Solver() {
    for ( int boxnum = 0; boxnum < 9; ++ boxnum ) {
        for ( int cellnum = 0; cellnum < 9; ++ cellnum ) {
            boxes[ boxnum ][ cellnum ]
                = &grid[ boxnum/3*3 + cellnum/3 ][ boxnum%3*3 + cellnum%3 ];
        }
    }
}
```

Checked code… I believe this is the pattern you're going for.

Comment: @dbger: because that code is using a GCC extension, and the extension is apparently fickle.

Comment: Unfortunately you're right. I tested my little test code at the end in Code::Blocks, which allowed it, but VC++ 2010 doesn't. So now I need to figure out how to create the nested for loop that handles turning a full 9x9 into 9 3x3's.

Comment: @NateD: Is this loop not what you need? If you mean you instead now want to write to a `int *boxes[9][3][3]`, then just change to `boxes[ boxnum ][ row ][ col ] = &grid[ boxnum/3*3 + row ][ boxnum%3*3 + col ];`

Comment: I'm an idiot; your first pattern is exactly right, I just didn't read the code close engough. Thank you again!

Comment: @NateD: Code::Blocks is an IDE, not a compiler. It can use VC++ as a compiler too. I assume you meant to say MinGW, no?

Comment: @mingos: yeah, I did mean MinGW.

Answer (score 1):

See that you have

```
 int *boxes[gridSize][gridSize];
```

Just make a test and change it to:

```
 int boxes[gridSize][gridSize];
```

You can do this for example (I'm using Visual C++ Console Application to test this):

```
 int boxes[gridSize][gridSize] = {
 {1, 3, 5},      /* y[0][0], y[0][1], y[0][2] */
 {2, 4, 6},      /* y[1][0], y[1][1], y[1][2] */
 {3, 5, 7}       /* y[2][0], y[2][1], y[2][2] */
```

};

Visual C++ doesn't accept this:

```
int test[2][2];
test[0]= { 1, 2 }; // error C2059: syntax error : '{'   
cout << test[0][1];
```

Comment: That's not what he wants… he wants to convolve by indirection.

Comment: You can't initialize a member variable (except `static` and of integral type) directly in the declaration.

Comment: The test code at the end is a GCC extension. (Which apparently breaks with multidimensional arrays.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it wants the lvalue to be:

```
&boxes[0][0] = ...
```

Comment: The result of `&` is never an lvalue.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Ah...then it would be just boxes[0][0].

Answer (score 0):

You declare `boxes` as `boxes[9][9]` so in order to initialize it, you would need to specify `boxes[0][0]`.  Well at least initialize that memory block.

I may be mistaken but it looks like you didn't want to make `boxes` a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the example code given by you works. Atleast my compiler is not able to digest it (gcc 4.2).
The reason for that is {...} are used while initialization and what you are doing is assignment.

u can try this

```
for (unsigned i=0; i < gridSize; ++i) {
     for (unsigned j=0; j < gridSize; ++j) {
            boxes[i][j] = &theGrid[i][j];
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
   int buf[2][2];
   cout << typeid(buf[0]).name();
}
```

This pseudo program prints the equivalent of `int [2]`. This means that the type of `buf[0]` is an `array of 2 integers`.

In C++ an array is a non modifiable Lvalue. It can be initalized but not assigned to.

Your code attempts to assign to `boxes[0]` and this is ill-formed. The solution of course is as suggested by Potatoswatter and many of the above posts